# Best practice for concatenation in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, concatenation

My row has a NVARCHAR value in a certain column. I want to be able to concatenate onto this value eg, if the row stores "Hello," I want to be able to run a db.Execute command to keep the "Hello" and tag on " my name is Earl" so that "Hello, my name is Earl" is stored in the row.

What is the best practice for doing this?

```
db.Execute("UPDATE table SET description = description + '--@0 likes this' WHERE id = @1",user, id);
```

This doesnt accept the parameters and actually inserts @0and @1 into the database. Why is this ?

Comment: Could you not use a view that includes the concatenation in order to query the data? That is, store it in "pure" form and query it in the less pure form.

Comment: Or you could use a trigger - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175943.aspx

Comment: What type of object is `db`?  `Webmatrix.Data.Database`?

Comment: Yes, it is WebMatrix.Data.Database. Initalised by a call to var db = Database.Open("database");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but try moving `@0` out of the single quotes:

```
db.Execute(@"
    UPDATE table 
    SET description = description + @0 + ' likes this' 
    WHERE id = @1",user, id);
```

Comment: *Facepalm*. Of course, this fixed it! Thanks for the answer; in defense of my silliness it was 2 in the morning! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table myTable with a message column you want to concat and the row id is 5 ...

```
UPDATE myTable
SET message = concat(message, N' my name is earl')
WHERE id = 5;  -- some where condition that identifies row(s)
```

Comment: What is the N' here for? I have never seen this kind of notation before :)

Comment: `N'string'` is for nvarchar representation as opposed to varchar of `'string'`

Comment: When I try this, I get the error ''concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.', however, when I try my code above, the parameters are not passed into the query.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue that the OP is having... his query isn't being properly parameterized, regardless of how he's trying to concatenate.

Comment: I'll leave this up here as not the correct answer (so others don't answer the same) and then delete tomorrow after the right answer ...